# "No implementation for kind" importing data to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am attempting to use the below [loader class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata?csw=1#Python_Creating_loader_classes) to import data from a `bulkloader` generated CSV:

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
from market import Market


class MarketLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
            bulkloader.Loader.__init__(
                self, 'Market',
                [('url', str),
                ('market_name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                ('parent_market_name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                ('last_modified', 
                    lambda x: dateutil.datetime.strptime(
                    x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date()),
                ('key',str),
                ('timestamp',
                    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(
                    x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date())

                ])

loaders = [MarketLoader]
```

**CSV data:**

> url,market_name,parent_market_name,last_modified,key,timestamp
>   somedata,moredata,yadata,2013-09-14T03:34:22,123143244,2013-09-14T03:34:22

Adjusting the property formatters or omitting them altogether does nothing to prevent this error being received:

> 02:22 PM Application: s~myapp 02:22 PM Uploading data
>   records. [INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20131005.142241 [INFO
>   ] Throttling transfers: [INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
>   [INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second [INFO    ] Entities
>   inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second [INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 184, in 
>       run_file(**file**, globals())   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 180, in run_file
>       execfile(script_path, globals_)   File "/home/myuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 4403, in 
>       main(sys.argv)   File "/home/myuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 4394, in main
>       result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 2469, in Run
>       self.action(self)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 4103, in **call**
>       return method()   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 3915, in PerformUpload
>       run_fn(args)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 3806, in RunBulkloader
>       sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py",
>   line 4419, in Run
>       return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py",
>   line 4230, in _PerformBulkload
>       LoadConfig(config_file)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py",
>   line 3897, in LoadConfig
>       Loader.RegisterLoader(cls())   File "/home/azureuser/gaeccscrm/Market_loader.py", line 19, in **init**
>       lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py",
>   line 2698, in **init**
>       GetImplementationClass(kind)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py",
>   line 968, in GetImplementationClass
>       implementation_class = db.class_for_kind(kind_or_class_key)   File "/home/azureuser/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py",
>   line 296, in class_for_kind
>       raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind) google.appengine.ext.db.KindError: No implementation for kind 'Market'

The stacktrace always mentions the last formatter, regardless of which one is set as the last.

Comment: Are you using polymodel?

Comment: @TimHoffman, no not in this app.